flink dynamic window adjust based on the completed window
My idea is to set a parameter that will adjust its value based on the data of each window, and use this value to adjust the size of the next window. How should I implement this function
Flink is unable to dynamically change window size, I currently have no idea

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Flink supports creating windows using custom WindowAssigner and Trigger, where you can decide which window a StreamRecord belongs to dynamically during runtime. You may check DataStream API for public methods related to these classes for their usage.
